# Shared Custom Code Analysis Rules with VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am having an issue with sharing custom code analysis rules I just can't seem to get past. We are using VSTS with a single team project structure.

**Here is my source structure**

- Team Project

  - _Configuration

    - Custom Rules.ruleset
  - Project A

    - Development

      - Phase2Dev

        - Source

          - .csproj files
    - Main

      - Source

        - .csproj files
  - Project B
  - ... Project Z

Then in the project file I reference the _Configuration\Custom Rules.ruleset file and it uses relative paths like I expect.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  ...
  <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\..\..\..\..\_Configuration\Custom Rules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  <RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The issue is this: When I branch from Main to Phase2Dev (which is inside the Development folder) the relative path is no longer correct and will have to be corrected manually. It will also have to be corrected again when merging back to Main. I know I can remove the Development folder but we use a lot of branches and that would clutter up the folder structure which I would like to avoid, if possible.

**Edit**

Based on Daniel's response below I should share some more details. "Project A" in this case is one of about 50 small to mid size projects. We only want to maintain one set of code rules for all of them which is why I have them located in the folder structure outside of the project scope.

So my question: Is there a better way to do this which doesn't rely on the source being the same number of levels deep in the folder structure?

Answer (score 2):

Your code analysis rules should be able to evolve along with the application without affecting other branches. Move the `_Configuration` folder to within your branches.

If you want to share the CodeAnalysis rule across multiple Solutions then you can package it in a Nuget Package and have each project take a dependency on the package.

Comment: Daniel, I updated my question with some clarification on my situation. See below the edit for more information.